# initialized with itself [-Werror=init-self]

Tags: c++, database, cryptography

I'm compiling my own coin and i encounter a problem that i can't get over it, i can't see how can i solve this, I've tried them all, so the line where the problem lies is here

```
BlockchainExplorer::BlockchainExplorer(INode& node, Logging::ILogger& 
logger) :
node(node), 
logger(logger, "BlockchainExplorer"),
database(database),
state(NOT_INITIALIZED), 
synchronized(false), 
observersCounter(0) {
}

BlockchainExplorer::~BlockchainExplorer() {}
```

And the error that i'm getting is this

> ../BlockchainExplorer/BlockchainExplorer.cpp: In constructor ‘CryptoNote::BlockchainExplorer::BlockchainExplorer(CryptoNote::INode&, Logging::ILogger&)’:
>   ../BlockchainExplorer/BlockchainExplorer.cpp:149:1: ***error: ‘CryptoNote::BlockchainExplorer::database’ is initialized with itself [-Werror=init-self]***
>    BlockchainExplorer::BlockchainExplorer(INode& node, Logging::ILogger& logger)

What could be the problem, anyone some ideas? Thanks in advance

Comment: `database(database)`? There's no `database` argument, so you use the member variable `database` to initialize the member variable `database`.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude here is the full code https://pastebin.com/m7qm8UQR

Comment: We don't need the full code, the error is there in plain sight. You use the `BlockchainExplorer::database` variable to initialize the `BlockchainExplorer::database` variable. That makes no sense. Perhaps you meant `database()` in the constructor member initializer list?

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude I did what you said, and now i get this error `../BlockchainExplorer/BlockchainExplorer.cpp:155:21: error: value-initialization of reference type ‘CryptoNote::IDataBase&’
   observersCounter(0)`

Comment: Ah, so we *did* need more code. Then learn how to create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). As for your problem, if you have a member variable that is a reference, it *must* be initialized to reference an actual object. You can't make it reference itself (that too makes no sense). You simply have to modify your code to pass a (pointer to, or reference to) a "database" object as *argument*, and use that when initializing. Or not have `database` be a reference.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude i can't just start create the code because this same code is used in most of alt coins, so, if it works for them, i wonder why is not working for me, i've searched online for a similiar problem and i found just one person reffering to this problem and nobody replied to his problem, so maybe i'm compiling it wrongly? Is there a problem if i just ignore this error? I'm not the best coder espescially in C++ some suggestion would be great, thanks

Comment: Which part of the error message are you having problems with?

Comment: @juanchopanza thanks for the help, the main problem is this `error: ‘CryptoNote::BlockchainExplorer::database’ is initialized with itself [-Werror=init-self]`

Comment: That is because `CryptoNote::BlockchainExplorer::database` is initialized with itself.

Comment: So, how do i fix this ?

Comment: @Ilie - You appear to be in in a grey area, where you can't really provide the MCVE because its someone else's code. Please post a link to the project you are attempting to compile; or better, the Git commands to clone it. Please also state your platform and compiler version, like Fedora 26 with GCC 7.

Comment: @jww thanks for the help, i am trying to work with bytecoin, the git is here https://github.com/amjuarez/bytecoin, my specs are Ubuntu 17.04, C compiler identification is GNU 6.3.0, Boost version: 1.62.0, thanks a lot for the help.

Comment: the code node(node), database(database) doesn't make sense.